# How can I specify a generic MutableSet, that demands existence of a update method, in a typed signature (Python >3.9)?

Tags: python, generics, typing, abstract-base-class

I have written a library. Some of its functions and methods operate on sets of Hashables, e.g.:

```
def some_function(my_set: set[Hashable]) -> None:
    ...
    my_set.update(...)
    ...
```

**How can I define something like an UpdatableSet** (and use it instead of "set" in the signature of some_function), **that demands existence of an update method, but allows for using some other class (from an external library) than set**, that provides all necessary methods, in function calls?

```
def some_function(my_set: UpdatableSet[Hashable]) -> None:
    ...
    my_set.update(...)
    ...

from intbitset import intbitset  # see PyPI
some_set = intbitset(rhs=100)
some_function(some_set)
```

MutableSet[Hashable] is not enough, since it does not guarantee that there is an update method.

I use MyPy for type checking.

---

I thought of something like the following, but the register method is not found. And I do not know, if this is the right approach. Maybe defining some generic protocol would be the right way.

```
class UpdatableSet(MutableSet[_T], Generic[_T], ABC):
    def update(self, other) -> None:
        pass

UpdatableSet.register(set)
UpdatableSet.register(intbitset)
```

Comment: Is there a lot of methods required? If not, maybe use [`Protocol`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html)? Also note that thanks to implementation details you can create subclass of `(Mutable)Set` and `Protocol` that will define `update`. It will work properly as long as you use it only as type annotation (no `isinstance` checks, no subclassing etc.) after adding type-ignore to class defn.

Comment: The proper and type-safe solution would be generic `Protocol[T]` that defines all methods of `set` you need. If there's only 5-6 methods, it's also convenient enough.

Comment: @SUTerliakov: The number of methods is small enough in my case. I tried it with your proposal and it worked. If you like, give you comment as answer and I will vote for it.

Comment: I found out, why I thought, that the register method is not found in my example: The reason is a bug in PyCharm (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35190).

Comment: @SUTerliakov: T think your proposal works because a generic set is contravariant in the type variable. My next try was to define a protocol to specify an extended version of a dictionary. But here, some of the methods use the type parameters in the specification of the method parameters (means: type variable needs to be decared as beeing contravariant) and others in the specification of the return values (means: covariance needed). Since the same type variable cannot be declared both contravariant and covariant, and a protocol cannot by used to declare such interfaces, right?

Comment: Please ask another question about dictionary, it's hard to tell without looking at your code

Comment: @SUTerliakov Please ignore my last comment. I found help with that topic on https://gitter.im/python/typing#. My comment is just wrong. (What is the recommended procedure in such cases? Deleting my comment?)

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @SUTerliakov answers the question, and I was able to solve the problem this way:

> The proper and type-safe solution would be generic Protocol[T] that defines all
> methods of set you need. If there's only 5-6 methods, it's also convenient enough. –
> SUTerliakov
> Apr 12 at 19:34